# Problem executing scripts APT after 'sudo apt update'

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, python-3.9

When I type `sudo apt-get update`, I get 2 errors, I have known from some similar questions that they're related to Python, all that is because I tried to replace python3.8 by python3.9 as the python by default version on my Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

`E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'`

`E: Sub-process returned an error code`